# Restricting uploads to PDFs and MS Word files

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm making a file uploader using PHP and want to restrict it to PDFs and Microsoft Word files. However, it's currently allowing uploads from all file types to the database. How can I restrict it to only allowing PDFs and Microsoft Word files?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

# Check if a file has been uploaded
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']))

# Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        # Connect to the database
        $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("webproject", $dbLink) or die(mysql_error());

        /* if(mysql_connect()) {
          die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysql_error());
          } */

        # Gather all required data
        $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $filemime = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'] == "application/pdf" || $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "application/msword");
        $size = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
        $subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        # Create the SQL query
        $query = "
                INSERT INTO file(
                    Filename, Filemime, Filesize, Filedata, subjects, name, email, phone, Created
                )
                VALUES (
                    '{$filename}', '{$filemime}', {$size}, '{$data}', '{$subjects}','{$name}','{$email}','{$phone}', NOW()
                )";

        # Execute the query
        $result = mysql_query($query, $dbLink);

        # Check if it was successfull
        if ($result) {
            echo "Success! Your file was successfully added!";
        } else {
            echo "Error! Failed to insert the file";
            echo "<pre>" . mysql_error($dbLink) . "</pre>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error!
                    An error accured while the file was being uploaded.
                    Error code: " . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];
    }

# Close the mysql connection
mysql_close($dbLink);


# Echo a link back to the mail page

echo "<p><a href='index.html'>Click here to go back home page!.</a></p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how your code actually works, but if you replace your second if at the top by this, the program will run only if the type is pdf or word, other files will cause this error: "Error! An error accured while the file was being uploaded. Error code: ". $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];" to occur

```
 if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0 && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']=='application/pdf' || $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']=='application/msword' || $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'))
```

Your first if: if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) has no braces... that's not a very good practice.

Comment: This is required for server validation (a good thing). However, you should also include the `accept="..."` attribute on the input element in the HTML form, which will restrict the dialog's behavior. Client-side restrictions like `accept` won't stop someone determined to break your application (that's what the server-side validation is for), but it makes for a better UX for the average user.

Comment: thanks a lot. its working now I can upload .PDF and .DOC files but cant upload .Docx file. why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a extract from a function I sometimes use:

```
 function CheckFile ($file){

      $mimeTypes = array(
                    "application/pdf",
                    "application/msword",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                    "application/excel",
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    "application/x-excel",
                    "application/x-msexcel",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                $fileExtensions = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx");
                if (in_array($file['type'], $mimeTypes) &&
                        in_array(end(explode(".", $file["name"])), $fileExtensions)) {
                    return true;
                }

 }
```

Call it with `CheckFile($_FILES['uploaded_file'])` It will return true if the doc is a pdf word or excel file

**Edit:**

One way to use it would be like so:

```
 if (!CheckFile($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
     ?>
            <p>Sorry, your file was not of the correct type</p>
      <?php
     exit();
 }
```

Comment: I am confused. where should I include function codes? sorry I am beginner in php thtsway. but I really appreciated your positive quick response. once again thanks a lot.

Comment: `if (!CheckFile($_FILES['uploaded_file']))` will evaluate to `true` if the file was not valid, note the `!` place the check before you go on to process the file, the function itself is normally included at the beginning or end of the file

Comment: I am trying! but thanks a lot. really much appreciated.